# Xamarin.Forms: Nothing happens when I try migrate to AndroidX by Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, androidx, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to migrate my project to AndroidX using the Visual Studio for Mac, but when I use the option on the interface (like suggesting on microsoft documentation) nothing happens.

I find some similar questions on AndroidStudio, but the answer was to update the gradle file but that is not my case.

The repository I want to update is this: https://github.com/aismaniotto/TrucoScorerClassic

Comment: There are some notices about migrating to AndroidX from [Automatic migration in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/androidx-migration#automatic-migration-in-xamarinforms), then you need to update ToolBar and Tabbar to use their corresponding AndroidX type `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` and `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout`, you can take a look [Package Name Change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/androidx#package-name-change)

Comment: I remove the `TabLayoutResource` and the `ToolbarResource` and nothing change, when I try the visual studio tool to migrate, any thing happens :/
Any idea?

Comment: do you update `ToolBar` and `Tabbar` to use their corresponding AndroidX type `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` and `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout` in Android project **Resources--layout**?

Comment: I updated, but still nothing change... it's normal nothing change?

Comment: Can you compile your project now? Is there some error message? You can take a look:[AndroidX with Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/androidx),AndroidX is a major improvement to the original Android Support Library, which is no longer maintained. AndroidX packages fully replace the Android Support Library by providing feature parity and new libraries you can use in your Android applications. can not see some changes from appearance.

Comment: Yes, after that, still compiling and no error message, but nothing in the entire project was modified (I see this on git). I also watched the Xamarin Show about the AndroidX e I guess, actually, nothing should change, right? I do the same thay does there, and, by debug, I saw the androidx packaage as base of `FormsAppCompatActivity`, so, I guess, is finished, right?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. AndroidX is a major improvement to the original Android Support Library, nothing else changed.